# UIToolBar アイテムの位置をコードで指定する方法をお教え下さい

Tags: ios, swift

TextFieldを押すとPickerとToolbarが出るようにプログラミングしたんですが、Toolbarのitemの位置指定の仕方がわかりません。どのように書けばいいのかご教授お願いします。イメージは以下のような感じです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

`UIToolBar`の`Bar Button Item`の配置は、`Fixed Space Bar Button Item`と`Flexible Space Bar Button Item`を使って、アイテム間の空きを調節するという方法をとります。
Storyboard上では、下図のように`Flexible Space Bar Button Item`を挿入すると、両サイドにアイテムを配置することができます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

プログラムでも、これとおなじことを行います。

`UIToolBar`のインスタンスを`toolBar`とします。

```
// 左のBar Button Item
let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Item1", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
// Flexible Space Bar Button Item
let flexibleItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
// 右のBar Button Item
let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Item2", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
// 3つを配列にする。
let items = [item1, flexibleItem, item2]
// 配列を、UIToolBarのプロパティitemsに代入
toolBar.items = items
```