# UITextField内のUIPickerViewのUIBarButtonItemのセンタリングってできますか？

Tags: swift

お世話になります。
表題の通りです。

UITextFieldをタップした時、UIPickerViewが下から出てきた時に、「完了」とか「Done」とかの終了ボタンを設置するのですが、これって画面（View）の真ん中に表示することはできますか？

現在のコードは下記の通りで、左隅によっている状態です。
できれば真ん中に配置がしたいのですが、お解りになる方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授願います。

```
textField.inputView = pickerView
        var toolBar: UIToolbar!
        toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/6, self.view.frame.size.width, 40.0))
        toolBar.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2, y: self.view.frame.size.height-20.0)
        toolBar.barStyle = .BlackTranslucent
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        toolBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        let toolBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "完了", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController3.tappedToolBarBtn(_:)))
        toolBarBtn.tag = 1
        toolBar.items = [toolBarBtn]
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

こんなやり方があるようです。`toolBar.items = [toolBarBtn]`の行を次の2行で置き換えてみてください。

```
        let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        toolBar.items = [spacer, toolBarBtn, spacer]
```

---

(追記)こちらにわかりやすいスレがありました。この応用ですね。
[UIToolBar アイテムの位置をコードで指定する方法をお教え下さい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/13163/uitoolbar-%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%8D%E7%BD%AE%E3%82%92%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%A7%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%82%92%E3%81%8A%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%95%E3%81%84)

Comment: 有難うございます。お陰様で出来ました。簡単でした。